# datebox usesetbutton doesn't work

Tags: datebox

I love the datebox plugin, but am having trouble customizing it. In "calbox" mode (the full calendar), I want the user to choose only a month/year combination. So I disabled the days part of the calendar using CSS, like so:

```
.ui-datebox-griddate {
    display: none;
    }
```

This gives the following, which is ALMOST what I want:

[image]

... but as you can see there is no way for the user to actually set a month/year combo and put it into the input field.

So after researching the Datebox site, I came across [this page](http://dev.jtsage.com/dboxdev/api/useSetButton/), which says that to show a button to set the date, you use the useSetButton.

So in data-options in the `<input>` field, I set useSetButton to true, like so:

```
data-options='{"mode":"calbox","calUsePickers": true, "calYearPickMin":2008, "useSetButton": true, "calYearPickMax":"NOW", "beforeToday": true, "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m"}'  placeholder='click icon to select month'/>
```

... but no dice. The calbox does not change -- no "set" button is added. It remains exactly the same as the graphic above.

Any suggestions on how I could get this to work? thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be calbox mode?  This is pretty simple to do with the "datebox" mode, and the dateFieldOrder option. (http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/api/dateFieldOrder/) - Note the "useSetButton" does not, nor is intended to work with calbox

Comment: belated thank-you-very-much, that helped. No it doesn't have to be calbox mode, the datebox works just fine. Fixed!